# XCTest - how to handle scrolling of list

Tags: xcode, swift3, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, ios-ui-automation

I am using xcode 8.3.3, swift, and XCTest.  I am wondering what the best approach to handle scrolling is when you plan to run your tests against multiple simulators and have a list displayed.  Since the screen size may change based on the simulator being used, the element you want to select to scroll up on may or may not be displayed.

If I have a list with x # of elements, how do I best approach which element to use to scroll the list up to have the next set of elements displayed on the screen so that the tests will run on multiple simulators of different screen sizes?

When we do "po XCUIApplication()" we see all the elements in the list, so in order to know which one is the last one displayed on the screen, we would have to look through each element and do a checked like isDisplayed or something to find the last element currently displayed ... but I was hoping there is a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element you want to use is displayed when you do `po XCUIApplication()` then you should just be able to `tap()` it without having to scroll it into view. The framework will handle the scrolling automatically if it can find the element.

Comment: Interesting!! I didn't realize it would do this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article I wrote discussing how to use SBTUITestTunnel for scrolling:

https://rlukasik.medium.com/using-sbtuitesttunnel-for-scrolling-in-xcuitests-2e166440ca73